# mysql alter table getting timeout due to huge records

Tags: mysql

while altering the table in mysql using below command its getting timeout.

`ALTER TABLE TABLE1 CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;`

what has been observed that this is working fine where records are less.

increasing the timeout in mysql client did not work. Is there anything else what can be done?

[image]

[image]

i see net_read_timeout as 30

could this be the issue

Comment: Which client are you using? (Hopefully it's not PhpMyAdmin..... )

Comment: mysql query browser

Comment: This one? [Please note that development of MySQL Query Browser has been discontinued.](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/query/) ?  Then, Please, use a supported client....

Comment: Perhaps you increased the wrong timeout parameter

Comment: any suggestion for supported client

Comment: @shadow, what should be the correct parameter

Comment: "any suggestion for supported client" sorry, that's an off topic question here,  there are enough MySQL clients, and it's up to you if you like them, or not...

Comment: [connect_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_connect_timeout) seems to be the correct one, but a client can decide to disconnect earlier...

Comment: There are various timeouts.  How long befors it timed out?  `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%timetout%';

Comment: Caution -- If the data utf8 bytes stored in a latin1 column, the `CONVERT TO` will make things worse.  That command should be used _only if_ non-English characters are correctly encoded in "latin1" (assuming the is the definition.)

Comment: You should take this opportunity to go to `utf8mb4`, not just utf8.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: i checked the show SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES and found that net_read_timeout is 30 but i do not have rights to change this, could this be the issue

Comment: @user190245: Please do some research before asking. (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34369376/what-is-mysqls-wait-timeout-net-read-timeout-and-net-write-timeout-variable )

Comment: with due respect @Luuk, thanks for pointing me to the article and added advice when someone is already working on the issue and disturbed when none of the solution is working for him. your extra advice is like a fuel to the fire. i really appreciate.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an update on the findings that we had while implementing the utf8mb4 changes.

There were many tables and no. of records were high. Therefore , we were altering the tables dynamically after fetching the table names but the process was failing midway. But we did not notice that the process was failing where the  command had already been executed. So, after finding that the table is already altered , process failed with timeout, we skipped and moved to other tables.

Comment: Please read: [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), because this does not seem to be an answer to your question.